# PHP+Zend or Django

Tags: php, web-applications, nginx, webserver, tornado

I am trying to develop a real time web application which is required to have scalable and concurrent architecture. Upto now I have nginx as a reverse proxy server. And tornado as the main server. Since tornado is python based, I am planning to use Django. 
But I wanted to know if PHP would be a better choice, seeing the web application's requirement? I dont want to loose the non-blocking functionality of the architecture though.

System Requirements :

1. Able to serve concurrently to 1000's of users at a time.
2. The system is collaborative like Google Docs.
3. Some of the client requests require some time to get processed, these may be:
   (a) Database Requests                                                                      (b) Computation Requests
4. Security is an important aspect too.

Edit 1:
Reading more about it, I gather that Tornado provides minimum basic functionality that is expected of a webserver.If we need more extensive functionality we could use Django, but in that case the system would loose its asynchronous nature. Am I right?

Comment: Is non-blocking/asynchronous a requirement or not? Django != Tornado. Django is not asynchronous. I'm fairly sure Zend isn't either.

Comment: I'd recommend just using Tornado in that case.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be for sure, you'd have to show a full list of requirements and outcomes.  If you have specifics on what the application will do it would help as well.  Obviously, if time is a factor, you should consider how good your developers are with each language, because sometimes  shipment is more important than milliseconds of speed.  Python is most likely faster, but Zend is full on feature packed.